# How to read conversation while writing long message

Tags: sms

When I'm replying to an sms, writing area can take whole screen space.

As I've written text which is long enough, previous messages from that person at the top dissapear.

How can I view them?

Up-to-date Android 2.3.6 on Samsung Galaxy Mini 2

Answer (score 1):

This may sound dumb, but have you tried to scroll the view ?

Or if there is really no space left to view the text list, just hide the keyboard (return key).

Comment: Yes, I've tried, doesn't work. Even if keyboard is hidden, text field occupies all screen space.